# Upload multiple files with JQuery blueimp

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I am trying to perform multiple fileupload with blueimp jquery fileupload library. link to library - https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

The files are uploading. But only a single file is uploading at a time. Multiple files are also uploading but single file is getting uploaded once. I am not sure what the error is.

**PHP**

```
<?php

// A list of permitted file extensions
$allowed = array('png', 'jpg', 'gif','zip', 'html','php', 'py', 'jpeg', 'txt');
for ($i=0; $i < count($_FILES); $i++) { 
if(isset($_FILES['files']) && $_FILES['files'][$i]['error'] == 0){

    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['files'][$i]['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error 1", "extension": "'.$extension.'"}';
        exit;
    } 
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files'][$i]['tmp_name'], __DIR__.'/upl/'.$_FILES['files'][$i]['name'])){
        echo '{"status": "success"}';
    }
}
else {
    echo '{"status":"error"}';
    exit;
}

}

?>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="message">
<h1>Files to be uploaded: </h1>
</div>
<div class="result">
</div>
<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="upload">
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
 $('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'act',
    add: function(e,data) {
      console.log("added for uploading"); 
      console.log(data.files[0].name);
      if( $(".message").is(":hidden") ) {
        $(".message").show();
      }
      $(".message").append("<p>"+ data.files[0].name + "</p>");
      $("#upload").click(function(){
        data.submit();
      })
    },
    start: function (e) {
    console.log('start');
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
      console.log("success in uploading data");
      console.log(data);
      console.log(data.files[0].name);
        // $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        //     $('<p/>').text("file name: " + file.name).appendTo($(".message"));
        // });
      $(".message").hide();
      $(".result").append("Uploading files");
    },
    fail: function (e, data) {
      console.log(data);
      console.log("failed to perform");
        $.each(data.messages, function (index, error) {
            $('<p style="color: red;">Upload file error: ' + error + '<i class="elusive-remove" style="padding-left:10px;"/></p>')
            .appendTo('.message');
        });
    }
});
});
```

Multiple files are getting uploaded. but a single file is getting uploaded at a time. I mean if I submit 3 files, first file only will be sent first for uploading, then second file will be sent and finally third file will be sent. Instead of sending all the three files as an array. Each time a single file will be sent. i.e totally 3 arrays will be sent. And also can anyone help about performing chunking. Thanks!!

**UPDATE**
There is a problem in appending data to data.files, instead of appending files to the array it's creating a new object every time. But I am not sure why it is done!

Comment: Why there are a lot of `exit;`?

Comment: It is to prevent different situations of exit

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh is there any issue with the code ??

Comment: I didn't downvote you. I'm still checking your code lines.

Comment: Thanks @KhoaTruongDinh There is a small problem I found. Everytime when I add a file a new array is created and the file is added. I logged `data.files`. If I select multiple files only one file is being created in the array everytime. The .add event is not appending to the array I guess its creating a new array !!

Answer (score 1):

Finally after reading documentation a bit. I found it out that generally blueimp fileuploader makes one request per file. That is the reason why it is uploading each file different times whenever I upload different files.

To process multiple files for same request.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    url: 'act',
    maxChunkSize: 10000000,
    maxFileSize: 1000000000,
    singleFileUploads: false,
```

`singleFileUploads: false` is actually disabling single file uploads. I got it from documentation here -- https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#singlefileuploads

Thanks for all the help

Comment: Can any one help me how to upload multiple files using jquery plugin only. Kindly assist on this!!